# Spectral norm and matrices

Tags: real-analysis, matrices

How do we prove that for any $W \in \mathbb R^{mxn}$  with

$$\| W \|_{op} \le 1, \quad U^TW = 0, \quad WV = 0,$$

where $A = U \Sigma V^T$ is a singular value decomposition of $A$ and $U \in \mathbb R^{m \times r}$, $\Sigma \in \mathbb R^{r \times r}$, and $V \in \mathbb R^{n \times r}$, we can get

$$\| UV^T + W \|_{op} \le 1.$$

Comment: What do $A$ and $\Sigma$ have to do with what you're asking?

Comment: The dimensions don't match. $W$ is $n\times1\ $, $U$ is $m\times r$ and $V$ is $n\times r$. So, $UV^T+W$ is the sum of an $m\times n$ matrix and an $n\times 1$ vector, which makes no sense at all.

Comment: I think $W$ is $m\times n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ (instead of it being a vector) such that $$\|W\|\leq 1, \quad U^TW=0,\quad WV=0.$$ 
The norm of $B=UV^T+W$ is given by the spectral radius of $$B^TB=(VU^T+W^T)(UV^T+W)=VV^T+W^TW.$$ Let $\tilde{V}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times {n-r}}$ be such that $[V,\tilde{V}]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is orthonormal and $\tilde{V}^TV=0$. The matrix $B^TB$ is orthogonally similar to
$$
[V,\tilde{V}]^TB^TB[V,\tilde{V}]=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&\tilde{V}^TW^TW\tilde{V}\end{bmatrix}
$$
and therefore
$$
\|B\|=\max\{1,\|W\tilde{V}\|\}\leq\max\{1,\|W\|\}=1.
$$